# How can I loop salary amount against each employees?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want my python to print the name of `employees` one by one (in a loop) and let me add the salary `amount` against each employee and in the last create a dictionary (key-value) for me, the `key` is `employee` name and `value` is `amount` and I also want to print out the `total` amount of salary means the sum of all the salaries.
How can I do that
That is what I did so far:

```
employees = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"]
n=0
amonut= 0
try:
    for employee in employees:
        employee = employees[n]
        amount= int(input(amount))
        total = sum(amount)
        n=n+1
        print(total)
except:
    print("You can only type integer for amount")
```

I have no idea how to create a dictionary in the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
employees = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"]    
salary={}
for emp in employees:
    try:
       amount=int(input(f'Enter salary for {emp}: '))
       salary[emp]=amount
    except ValueError:
       print(f'Wrong salary input for {emp} ')
print(salary)
print('Total salary ',sum(salary.values()))
```

Comment: just  ```for emp in employees```

Answer (score 3):

I mean... something like this?

```
employee_names = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"]
employee_salaries = {}
for employee in employee_names:
    while True:  # Input validation loop
        try:
            employee_salaries[employee] = int(input(f"Enter {employee}'s salary: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
print(employee_salaries)
total = sum(employee_salaries.values())
print(total)
```

Comment: You presented very nicely thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the **n** variable here. You can create a dictionary and add employee and amount to that

```
employees = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"]

employees_dictionary = dict()
total = 0
amount = 0

try:
    for employee in employees:
        amount= int(input(amount))
        employees_dictionary[employee] = amount
        total += amount
except:
    print("You can only type integer for amount")
    
print(employees_dictionary)
print(total)
```

Comment: Doesn't work  - try and run it yourself.

Comment: Check it again. amount variable was missing.

Comment: Checked and it works fine now.

Comment: This line is the problem - `amount= int(input(amount))`.  Also, the total should be out of the for loop.

Comment: Fixed that too. Code is now good to go. :)

Comment: Copy and paste the code and check it.

Comment: The code works as you asked in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242213/discussion-between-devang-sanghani-and-shaida-muhammad).